# How to write comma character in a SLIME EMACS window

Tags: lisp, slime

How can I write a "," (comma) character in the SLIME emacs window? The , key brings up the SLIME command prompt automatically.

Thanks, a Lisp beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert `,` by <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (Control-q and then comma). <kbd>C-q</kbd> is bound to `quoted-insert`, which can be generally used whenever you want Emacs to read a next input character and insert it instead of invoking a command bound to the input character.

Answer (score 3):

`,` only triggers REPL shortcut selection when input at the beginning of a line.  In all other cases, you can input a comma by typing `,`.

In the case of Common Lisp, since as long as you don't modify the reader, `,` can only occur within a quasi-quoted expression, this should not be a significant restriction.

If it really is a problem, refer to [Deokhwan Kim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145621/15517).

Comment: I accepted Deokhwan's answer, because I encountered this problem when I edited a previously evaluated line.